# Not able to click Logout Button eventhough able to identify the element in selenium webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

- **Environment** : IE11
- **Webdriver/Selenium version** : 3.141.59
- **Language** : java

**Selenium code:**

```
driver.findElementByXPath("//span[contains(text(),'Logout')]").click();**
```

**HTML code :**

```
<span class="v-menubar-menuitem-caption">Logout </span>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @Patrick Getting the following Exception
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: @Abhiram can you share your complete ``menubar`` HTML code and aslo please share your complete selenium code(method).

Comment: Because the exception you are getting is of ``Action`` class

Comment: @UpkarSingh shouldn't we use Actions class for this user action ? when i use normal click nothing happens

Comment: @Abhiram I don't know what action you are performing and what required, because i'm not able to view your HTML and selenium code. If you can share the code then share it.

Comment: Selenium code
Thread.sleep(20000);
driver.findElement("//span[contains(text(),'Logout')]").click();
System.out.println(driver.findElement("//span[contains(text(),'Logout')]").getText());
act.moveToElement(driver.findElement("//span[contains(text(),'Logout')]")).click().build().perform();

Comment: HTML code :
<div tabindex="0" class="v-menubar v-widget right v-menubar-right">
<span class="v-menubar-menuitem">
<span class="v-menubar-menuitem-caption">Logout</span>
</span></div>

Answer (score 0):

Have a small correction in your Selenium code:

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Logout')]")).click();

Comment: Getting the following Exception while using above code
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Cannot click on element
Build info: version: '3.141.59',
java.version: '1.8.0_74'

Comment: I have verified that element is displayed and clickable

Answer (score 0):

1. It might be the case the element is not present yet by the time you're trying to click it. Consider using [WebDriverWait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) in order to ensure that the element is really there and can be clicked, suggested code amendment:

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Logout')]"))).click();
   ```
2. It might be the case the element doesn't fit at the screen, try [maximizing](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Window.html#maximize--) the browser window so more elements could be displayed:

   ```
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   ```
3. In the majority of cases you should not be clicking the [`span`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp), I would rather expect an [`input`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) or a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: The button is built using span class. added the following code and check .But still doesnt work same exception is thrown
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Cannot click on element